# How to plot negative values in the base of an exponent

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, math-functions

I want to plot `f(x) = x^(2/3)` using python, however, I'm only able to get it to plot for the positive values of x.

Does anyone have any ideas where I'm going wrong?

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Define the function
def f(x):
    return x ** (2/3)

# Generate x values for both positive and negative x
x_positive = np.linspace(0, 10, 200)
x_negative = np.linspace(-10, 0, 200)

# Calculate corresponding y values for both sets of x values
y_positive = f(x_positive)
y_negative = f(x_negative)

# Plot
plt.figure(figsize=(8, 6))

# Plot for positive x
plt.plot(x_positive, y_positive, label=r'$f(x) = x^{2/3}$', color='blue')

# Plot for negative x
plt.plot(x_negative, y_negative, linestyle='dashed', color='blue')

plt.title('f(x) = x^(2/3)')
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('f(x)')
plt.grid(True)
plt.legend()
plt.ylim(-10, 10)  
plt.xlim(-10, 10)  
plt.axhline(y=0, color='black', linewidth=0.8)  # x-axis
plt.axvline(x=0, color='black', linewidth=0.8)  # y-axis
plt.show()
```

Which results in a warning, and a plot with half the x range.

```py
C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_35264\1241025677.py:3: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in power
  return x ** (2/3)
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks - it explains why I'm only seeing positive numbers but the solution proposed doesn't seem to solve my problem.
I tried:
```
def f(x):
    return np.sign(x) * (np.abs(x)) ** (2/3)
```
And the graph python produces looks like an s-shape where
positive values of x correspond to positive values of y, and
negative values of x correspond to negative values of y.
However, I think it should produce a v-shaped graph where
positive values of x correspond to positive values of y, and
negative values of x correspond to positive values of y.

Comment: By definition, `x**a` is mathematically defined only if `x > 0` when `a` is not an integer. So it's fair that numpy forces it that way. You could rephrase your function as `(x**2)**1/3`, which is equivalent to `abs(x) ** 2/3`; then it is defined for all non-zero `x`. I don't think `np.sign` make sense; I mean it would be `np.sign(x) ** 2/3` because `(xy)**a == x**a * y**a`, but then we run into the power of negative number dilemma again.

Comment: `x_negative = np.linspace(-10, 0, 200, dtype=np.complex128)`, which still produces `ComplexWarning`, but also plots the function.

Answer (score 1):

The reason only the plot for positive x values is visible in the graph of the function f(x) = x^(2/3) is because raising a negative number to the power of 2/3 results in a complex number. In a 2d graph, complex numbers cannot be directly plotted. So, the graph only shows the portion corresponding to the real values of x - which are the positive values.
But you can plot the absolute values of the negative x values and indicate the negative sign in the plot.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Define the function
def f(x):
    return np.power(np.abs(x), 2/3) * np.sign(x) # Here is the change

# Generate x values for both positive and negative x
x_positive = np.linspace(0, 10, 200)
x_negative = np.linspace(-10, 0, 200)

# Calculate corresponding y values for both sets of x values
y_positive = f(x_positive)
y_negative = f(x_negative)

# Plot
plt.figure(figsize=(8, 6))

# Plot for positive x
plt.plot(x_positive, y_positive, label=r'$f(x) = x^{2/3}$', color='blue')

# Plot for negative x
plt.plot(x_negative, y_negative, linestyle='dashed', color='blue')

plt.title('f(x) = x^(2/3)')
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('f(x)')
plt.grid(True)
plt.legend()
plt.ylim(-10, 10)  
plt.xlim(-10, 10)  
plt.axhline(y=0, color='black', linewidth=0.8)  # x-axis
plt.axvline(x=0, color='black', linewidth=0.8)  # y-axis
plt.show()
```

Comment: `x**(.666)` produces the warning and `np.nan` for the negative elements of `x`.  `nan` values are not plotted.  If `x` is complex (even with just a `0j` imaginary term), the result will be complex (and no warning).  The `np.abs()` will match the `((x**2)**(1/3)` or `np.abs(x)**(2/3)` cases.  I'm don't think your `f` should include the `sign` term.

Comment: Your first sentence is not mathematically correct.  In math terms, `x^(2/3)` is well-defined and will not produce imaginary results for negative inputs.  When x is -8, for example, the result is 4.  However, the computer doesn't realize that we asked for 2/3; it only sees 0.6666..., and that IS a problem.